# Can I upload CSV files to Android firebase?

Tags: android, csv, firebase

I am using Android firebase for the first time so please let me know can I upload CSV files from my mobile to firebase? if yes then how ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the ["the Stack Overflow question checklist"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) . You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You totally can. You can use [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) to store your files - csv, images, videos, etc.